# Sort Windows Event Log in order that entries were added

Tags: windows-10, event-log

Is there any way of sorting the Windows Event log entries in the order they were added?

Unfortunately I can't just sort by "Date and Time" because I'm investigating an issue where the time was changed, and the time was set backwards several times on this device (sometimes by a few months or up to a year).

Also I can tell by looking at the log that it is not sorted in this order necessarily by default (even though as far as I've seen new log entries always appear at the top) as sometimes the ordering goes from Dec 2021 to Nov 2023 and back multiple times without any entry for the time change.

[image: Event log excerpt]

Comment: There's likely a way with a custom filter, but it may need to be done via XML since the GUI is relatively limited. If it can be done via XML: _Create Custom View_ →Tab: _XML_ → Tick box: _Edit query manually_ → Paste XML for the filter → OK → Select the custom filter view from the nav tree

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden field, [EventRecordID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/eventschema-eventrecordid-systempropertiestype-element), that is

> *"The record number assigned to the event when it was logged."*.

According to [Flynn Weeks](https://blog.what2log.com/eventrecordid/) it

> *"can serve as a sort of backup identifier to determine the true order of events."*

Unfortunately I could not find a way to add that column in the GUI to sort. The field appears if the events are exported as XML, so it is possible to use some XML tool.

Another option is to use [FullEventLogView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html), from NirSoft, where the field is in the column `Record ID`.